# socket not firing after update from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to build a small app, it gets a file at random from gist.github and converts the gist to an image (I have not written this part and it works as expected).

Once the file is written to an svg I call socket method to emit a message to the client. On receiving the message the client should fetch a new version of the image and set it to the src attribute in the html.

Here is a truncated version of my server js code:

```
const PORT = 8080;
const SOCKET_PORT = 3000;
let interval = 5000;
const io = new Server(SOCKET_PORT);

const getRandomGists = () => {
  // some vars here
  fetch(rndGist)
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((body) => {
      const { window } = new JSDOM(body);
      const { document } = window;
      const codeBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".blob-code-inner");
      console.log(`rndGist: ${rndGist}. Time: ${now}`);
      return codeBlock;
    })
    .then((codeBlock) => {
      const fauxCode = new FauxCode(codeBlock, options);
      fs.writeFileSync(filename, fauxCode.render());
    })
    .then(() => {
      io.on("connection", (socket) => {
        socket.emit("imageUpdate", "Image updated"); // this only seems to work when hitting refresh in the browser
        socket.on("customMessage", (arg) => {
          console.log(arg);
        });
        console.log("Server should be emiting message");
      });
    });
};

getRandomGists();

setInterval(() => {
  getRandomGists();
}, interval);

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on: ${PORT}`));
```

In my client I am using this js:

```
const socket = io("ws://localhost:3000");

socket.on("imageUpdate", (arg) => {
  reloadImg("../img/fauxcode.svg");
  console.log(arg, `reloadImg from client`);
});

function reloadImg(url) {
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  fetch(url, { cache: "reload", mode: "no-cors" });
  const wrapper = document.querySelector(".code");
  wrapper.setAttribute(`src`, `${url}?timestamp=${now}`); // I tried adding this in order to generate a unique parameter on the filename
  socket.emit("customMessage", "Emiting from the client!");
}
```

The html file looks like this:

```
   <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="./img/fauxcode.svg" class="code" alt="Alt text" />
    <script type="module" src="js/client.js"></script>
```

Here is some console logging after a hard refresh:

```
rndGist: https://gist.github.com/pengzhile/448bfcfd548b3ae4e665a84cc86c4694. Time: 8:32:23
rndGist: https://gist.github.com/drewolson/4771479. Time: 8:32:30
Server should be emiting message
Server should be emiting message
Server should be emiting message
Emiting from the client!
Emiting from the client!
Emiting from the client!
Emiting from the client!
Emiting from the client!
Emiting from the client!
Emiting from the client!
Emiting from the client!
Emiting from the client!
rndGist: https://gist.github.com/omz/05f096319c23c4addba9. Time: 8:32:36
rndGist: https://gist.github.com/pkuczynski/8665367. Time: 8:32:42
```

I realise that my server code is opening a new connection each time the function gets called, which I am assuming is either not ideal, or maybe I should close that connection before opening another? Or I was wondering do I open the connection outside the `rndGist` function but then how do I access the socket parameter to emit the message after the function is done?

I have tried to make all the code examples succinct, if you need to see more just let me know.

I hope someone out there can see an obvious fix for this. TIA

Comment: you do not want `io.on("connection", (socket) => {` executing every 5 seconds, that's for sure. I'm trying to figure out what you're trying to do, but it's not coming to me

Comment: Server gets new image from gist. once that file is written it should emit a message to the client. Once that message is received, the client should fetch the new version of the file and write that to the image tag and update the HTML page. So this should reflect in the browser. Repeat this process for the interval variable (currently 5 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine you want more than one *client*, so, I believe this addresses that as well.

```
const PORT = 8080;
const SOCKET_PORT = 3000;
const interval = 5000;
const io = new Server(SOCKET_PORT);

// an array of client sockets
let clients = [];
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    clients.push(socket);
    socket.on("customMessage", (arg) => {
        console.log(arg);
    });
});
const getRandomGists = () => {
    fetch(rndGist)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => {
        const { window } = new JSDOM(body);
        const { document } = window;
        const codeBlock = document.querySelectorAll(".blob-code-inner");
        console.log(`rndGist: ${rndGist}. Time: ${now}`);
        const fauxCode = new FauxCode(codeBlock, options);
        fs.writeFileSync(filename, fauxCode.render());
        clients.forEach((socket, i) => {
            try {
                socket.emit("imageUpdate", "Image updated");
            } catch {
                // remove socket if there was an error?
                // This may be a naive way to do this though
                clients[i] = null;
            }
        });
        // remove "errored" clients
        clients = clients.filter(socket => socket);
    });
};

getRandomGists();

setInterval(getRandomGists, interval);

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on: ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: Awesome! That looks like it is working. Thank you so much. Still quite new to sockets, but keen to learn more, looks super useful.

Comment: @lharby - the only thing I'm not sure about is the "error checking" for disconnected sockets, as I said in my code, it's naive :p

Comment: I will see if I can test that, I assume there must be a `socket.close()` method or a way to close it manually? No worries, I still have some polishing to do :D